# Is there a re-frame interceptor like "path" that takes an additional dynamic ID?

Tags: clojurescript, re-frame

Background: The re-frame todomvc example, like most implementations, stores all todos as one big blob in local storage. That means the events that change a todo can have a path interceptor for a hard-code [:todos] path, and then the ->localStorage interceptor blindly writes "everything" to the todos key, confident "everything" is just the todos.

Problem: what if I have much the same scenario but for efficiency want to store each todo under a different key, by (1) assigning, say, a UUID then (2) creating the key as "TODO-" + uuid? The event vector then would contain the uuid of the todo being changed.

I *think* I just need an interceptor like "path" that can somehow look at the event to determine the uuid and narrow the "db" to just that todo, and then have a writer interceptor that understands how to get the key info from context. Does such a creature exist?

Or maybe I just write use reg-event-ctx and custom handle everything?

Or am I missing a more idiomatic solution?

Comment: After reviewing the use case of talking to an external server[1], in which case dynamic specificity working off the event is easy, methinks I just need to emulate that version 1 of example, perhaps writing a custom handler for localStorage, if it seems usefully generalizable, to support version 2. [1] https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/blob/develop/docs/Talking-To-Servers.md

Answer (score 1):

I faced this kind of problem in one of my projects. Here the solution I came up with:

```
(require '[re-frame.interceptor :refer [->interceptor get-effect get-coeffect assoc-coeffect assoc-effect]])

(defn path-by [path-key event->path]
  (->interceptor
    :id ::path-by

    :before
    (fn
      [context]
      (let [original-db  (get-coeffect context :db)
            event        (get-coeffect context :event)
            path         (or (event->path event)
                             (path-key original-db))
            original-db' (assoc original-db path-key path)]
        (assert (some? path)
                "Cannon get path neither from event->path nor from db.")
        (-> context
            (assoc ::original-db original-db')
            (assoc-coeffect :db (get-in original-db' path)))))

    :after
    (fn [context]
      (let [original-db (::original-db context)
            path        (path-key original-db)
            context'    (-> (dissoc context ::original-db)
                            (assoc-coeffect :db original-db))
            db          (get-effect context :db ::not-found)]
        (if (= db ::not-found)
          context'
          (->> (assoc-in original-db path db)
               (assoc-effect context' :db)))))))
```

Most of it is borrowed from re-frame's original [path](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/blob/464b3636450cc84c07943be9a1492dd192f343c4/src/re_frame/std_interceptors.cljc#L181) interceptor.

Here is the usage example:

```
(rf/reg-event-fx ::taks-viewed
  (path-by
    ::current-task
    (fn [[_ id]] id))
  (fn [{:keys [db]} [_ id]]
    {:db   (assoc db :loading true)
     :http {...}}))
```